# Not able to run command bundle exec Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new to Rspec, after doing setting such as installing gem and creating spec files, when i run `bundle exec spec`, i get th following errors

```
aditya@aditya-Inspiron-3543:~/orthoweb$ bundle exec rspec

    /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `ip' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000000443d038> (NoMethodError)
        from /home/aditya/orthoweb/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/carrierwave-cc2ab785a9d4/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:158:in `configure'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/carrierwave-cc2ab785a9d4/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
        from /home/aditya/orthoweb/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/aditya/orthoweb/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/aditya/orthoweb/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
        from /home/aditya/orthoweb/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/aditya/orthoweb/spec/controllers/beds_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/aditya/orthoweb/spec/controllers/beds_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `load'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'

gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'mongoid_paranoia' #refer this link for commands info 'https://github.com/simi/mongoid_paranoia'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'time_difference', '~> 0.4.2'

gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.2'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'letter_opener', group: :development

gem 'backbone-on-rails' #ADDED BY KUMAR ABINASH

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'hashie', '~> 3.3.1'
gem 'ventable'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', '~> 0.12.2.1'
gem 'carrierwave',:git => "git://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave.git"
gem 'global'
gem 'fiscali'
gem 'mongoid-ancestry'
gem 'inline_svg'

gem "bson"

gem "mongoid"
gem "moped", github: "mongoid/moped"
gem 'mongoid-history'
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
gem 'nested_form'
gem 'apipie-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails.git'
gem 'faker'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem 'seed_dump', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'pry-rails', :group => :development

gem 'will_paginate'

gem 'data-confirm-modal', github: 'ifad/data-confirm-modal'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'rspec-rails' 
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'awesome_print'
end 

group :test do 
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false

  gem 'capybara' 
  gem 'guard-rspec' 
  gem 'launchy' 
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt'
#gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'authority',:git => "git://github.com/nathanl/authority.git" 
gem 'rolify', :git => "git://github.com/EppO/rolify.git"

gem 'rmagick', '2.13.4'
gem 'nokogiri'

gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'mime-types'

gem 'sidekiq'

gem 'whenever', :require => false

gem 'state_machine'
gem 'state_machine-audit_trail'

# Use redis as session store
gem 'redis-store' , group: :production
gem 'redis-rails' , group: :production

#for client side validations
gem 'client_side_validations', github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form', github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form'
gem 'dicom'

gem 'high_voltage', '~> 2.3.0'
gem 'spreadsheet'

gem 'fog-aws'

gem 'gcm'
gem 'exception_notification'
```

Apllication.rb file is:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'csv'
require "bson"
require "moped"

Moped::BSON = BSON

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Orthograph
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    config.generators do |gen|
      gen.orm :active_record
    end

    config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true

    config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true

    # AUTO LOAD PATHS -- HEALTHGRAPH
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'controllers', '{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'services', '{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'uploaders', '{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'analytics', '{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'authorizers', '{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'workers', '{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'jobs', '{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'jobs','record_jobs', '{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'jobs','email_jobs', '{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'jobs','email_jobs','appointment_jobs' ,'{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'jobs','sms_jobs', '{**/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'jobs','sms_jobs','appointment_jobs' ,'{**/}')]



    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "patients")

    config.time_zone = "Mumbai"
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

    # config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
  end
end
```

can anyone tell me where the issue is, also please suggest if i need to add any more file here to get the question more clear
my caarierwave intializer file is

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?
config.storage = :file
config.asset_host = Rails.application.config.ip
else
config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
config.fog_credentials = {
provider: 'AWS',
aws_access_key_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
aws_secret_access_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
region: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
}
config.fog_directory = 'xxxxxxxx'
end
end
```

Comment: Problem appears to be in carrierwave initializer. Are you calling `.ip` on something incorrectly?

Comment: i have added the carrierwave initializer. file have alook @ Shadwell

Comment: Have answered but basically, yes, you were calling `.ip` on something incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the first two lines of your error message are:

```
/home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `ip' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000000443d038> (NoMethodError)
  from /home/aditya/orthoweb/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Which points to you having called a method `ip` on something (`Rails::Application::Configuration`) that doesn't have that method.

When you look at your carrierwave initializer file at the specified line (**:4:**). Line 4 is you trying to call:

```
config.asset_host = Rails.application.config.ip
```

So, the problem is that there is no `ip` method available.

You may just want to set it to something like:

```
config.asset_host = '0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: Rails.application.config.ip       when i run this on console i get , "http://localhost:3000"

Comment: when i set config.asset_host = '0.0.0.0' i get another error

Comment: You may need to set it to 'localhost:3000' then - I'm not exactly sure. But at least you've got past your original error.